# Is there the word "over-preoccupation"?

Tags: word-meaning, definition, prefixes

I've seen “over-preoccupation” in a paragraph and searched for the meaning, but I only came across results with "preoccupation" - without the "over".

Comment: to be overly preoccupied, not usually a noun.

Answer (score 1):

Let me quote [the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/over)

> We can use over as a **prefix** to mean ‘too much’. We connect over to the
>   word which comes after it, **sometimes with a hyphen** after over:
>
> *That new restaurant is overpriced if you ask me. (the meals are too
>   expensive)*
>
> *I didn’t enjoy the play. It was a student production, and everyone
>   seemed to be overacting.*

over-preoccupation = too much preoccupation